# Get next occurrence from RIGHT TO LEFT of a substring in a string (Java)

Tags: java, string

Say I have a string `s` like this:

```
s = "... *begin* - some-code-here - *end* ..."
i:                    ^
```

and an index `i` pointing to a position between `"*begin*"` and `"*end*"`, e.g., to the `'e'` of `"some"`.

To get the index of the (next) occurrence of `"*end"*`, I could use

```
s.indexOf("*end*", i)
```

Is there a similar way to get the index of the next `"*begin*"` to the left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
s.lastIndexOf("*begin*", i);
```

Comment: Oh man, seriously?? I thought, that just gives you the index of the very last occurrence. Didn't know you can use it with the `i`. But it makes perfect sense that it just goes backwards. I didn't even consider looking into the documentation of that one, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I want this answer to add as comment to wero's answer but due to low reputation I am unable to do so.

I think it should be like

```
s = s.substring(0, i);

s.indexOf("*begin");
```

Comment: if `s = "*begin* *begin*..."`, then this would give you the first `*begin*` and not the last.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the point. I have to deal with multiple occurrences of both `"*begin*"` and `"*end*"`. But you probably meant to write `s.lastIndexOf("*begin");`?